# How to detect boolean true and false in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code for date validate, when fill `28/02/2017` into input type text and press button.

First it's will alert `true` when see in code if first alert is `true` secone alert will alert `true` too. But my second is alert `false`.

What is my miskate for detect boolean

```
if(regex.test(txt) === true)
{
    alert("true");
    p.innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green'>Correct</h1>";
}
else
{
    alert("false");
    p.innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:red'>Wrong</h1>";;
}
```

.

```html
<input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="dd/mm/yyyy" />
<button onclick="isDate();">Check</button>

<p id="response"></p>
<script>
function isDate() {
    
    var regex = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g;
    
    var txt = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("response");
    
 alert(regex.test(txt));
 
 if(regex.test(txt) === true)
 {
  alert("true");
  p.innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green'>Correct</h1>";
 }
 else
 {
  alert("false");
  p.innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:red'>Wrong</h1>";;
 }  
} 
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason, adding console.log below the alert repeating the test, then removing the `===` and `true` it returns true then logs false... VERY strange!! spoookky

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that `regex.test()` will search the string and return `true` if there is a match.  If you then subsequently call `.test()` again it will continue from where it left off.

> #### Using `test()` on a regex with the global flag
>
> If the regex has the global flag set, `test()` will advance the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) of the regex. A subsequent use of `test()` will start the search at the substring of `str` specified by [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) ([`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) will also advance the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property).

From here: [MDN web docs – RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: work good sir..

Comment: Just a question, why it is working if you remove g modifier? thanks!

Comment: @Albeis If you remove the global flag it searches from the beginning every time.

Comment: Thanks! so removing global flag should be another solution right? regards

Comment: @Albeis ‘g’ stands for ‘global’ – the `g` modifier sets the `global` flag. And that affects the “If the regex has the global flag set” behavior described in the documentation.

Comment: @Albeis It depends on the string you're testing.  In this specific instance then removing the global flag would fix the issue, yes.

Comment: @Archer yes, on this specific instance. regards